# Google API create new User

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, zapier

I'm using Zapier and try to create a new User in Google.

The documentation is pretty unclear.

This is the request I'm making:

[image]

Now I understand, that I need to add authorization to the request.

1. How do I authorize the request? I created an API Token in the Google Cloud but this doesn't work as a GET parameter.
2. Is the Request right? Do I have to change something?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This appears to be using the Directory admin api for workspace accounts you could try and consult the documentation there https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest.   Since its creating google workspace users you should try using a service account authorization will be easer.

Comment: @DaImTo can you send like an example API request?

Comment: @BlockchainProgrammer try selecting the necessary endpoint at https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest and method. For example, `asps.get` https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/asps/get - there will be the API Explorer where you can test your requests. Let me know if you experience any issue with this

Answer (score 1):

Posting DalmTo's comment for visibility.

This appears to be using the Directory Admin API for Workspace accounts. You can consult the [Admin SDK: Directory API docs](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest) for this.

As it's creating Google Workspace users, you may want to try using a service account authorization.

For an example of an API request, selecting the necessary endpoint and method, e.g. [`asps.get`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/asps/get), and use the API Explorer to test your requests.